# The keyword 'then' is missing

Tags: crystal-reports

```
{FUELDELAY.STATUS} = "VENDOR RESPONSIBLE" and {FUELDELAY.FLIGHTDATE} in {?begtime1} to {?endtime1}
and if {?fuelserviceprovider} != ""  then {FUELDELAY.FUELSERVICEPROVIDER} in {?fuelserviceprovider}
and if {?station} != "" then {FUELDELAY.STATION} in {?station}
```

I don't see the syntax error, but Crystal Reports keeps telling me that "The keyword 'then' is missing."

Do any of y'all see the error?

Any help is much appreciated--thanks!

Comment: Are you tried parenthesis? like here in this tutorial?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/if_then_else.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two main errors in your syntax.

- The `!=`-operator is not valid Crystal-Syntax -> use the `not`-operator or `<>`-operator instead
- `and if ...` is not valid. The syntax is as follows (The `else`-part is optional):

  ```
  if <condition> then
     'Do something
  else
     'Do something different
  ```

---

So the following formula should work.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, because it's not clear from the question.

```
if
{FUELDELAY.STATUS} = "VENDOR RESPONSIBLE" and
{FUELDELAY.FLIGHTDATE} in {?begtime1} to {?endtime1}
and {?fuelserviceprovider} <> "" then
    {FUELDELAY.FUELSERVICEPROVIDER} in {?fuelserviceprovider}
else if {?station} <> "" then
    {FUELDELAY.STATION} in {?station}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
IF {FUELDELAY.STATUS} = "VENDOR RESPONSIBLE"
    AND {FUELDELAY.FLIGHTDATE} in {?begtime1} to {?endtime1}
    AND {?fuelserviceprovider} != ""
    AND {FUELDELAY.FUELSERVICEPROVIDER} in {?fuelserviceprovider}
    AND {?station} != ""
    AND {FUELDELAY.STATION} in {?station}
THEN
    //some code if true
ELSE
    //some code if false
```